# Updating XML node value using the condition in Python

Tags: python, xml

In the below XML, I want to parse it and update the value of "PolicyId" to some random value for example "POL111112NGJ" and "TransactionDate" to current date and time ONLY IF IT MEET THE CONDITION PolicyId == POL000002NGJ. Code I given below updates for all values of "PolicyId and TransactionDate", I want to update the value only if condition is TRUE. From the XML given, I expects to update for first 3 sets to same value of "PolicyId and TransactionDate". and 4th set to different value.

I tried adding the condition ~~~if ROW.attrib['PolicyId'] == 'POL000002NGJ': ~~~ I gets "KeyError: 'PolicyId'"

Could someone help me understand how to handle this?

```
--BEFORE UPDATING---

<TABLE>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL000002NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL000002NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL111111NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X4</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
</TABLE>


--AFTER UPDATING---

<TABLE>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL545678NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-27T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL545678NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3A2</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-27T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL111111NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X4</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
</TABLE>
```

Code i am using

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random, string

class TimestampUpdater(object):

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.meta_file = filepath
        self.tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\\XML\python.xml')

    def getMetadataTree(self):
        return self.tree

    def getMetadataRoot(self):
        return self.tree.getroot()
    
    def updatepolicyid(self):
        for ROW in self.getMetadataRoot().findall('ROW'): ##    
            PolicyId = ROW.find('PolicyId')
            
            if ROW.attrib['PolicyId'] == 'POL702965NGJ':
                
                x = 'POL' + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=6)) + 'NGJ'
                PolicyId.text = x
            #PolicyId.set('updated', 'yes')
            self.getMetadataTree().write(self.meta_file)
                   
    
    def updateLastModified(self):
            today = datetime.now()
            for ROW in self.getMetadataRoot().findall('ROW'): ##
                TransactionDate = ROW.find('TransactionDate')
                previous_update = datetime.strptime(TransactionDate.text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
                if previous_update < today:
                    TransactionDate.text = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
                    self.getMetadataTree().write(self.meta_file)
                    
                    

def print_file_content(filename):
    """Print contents of a file"""
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            print(line.rstrip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    metafile = 'output.xml'
    print("\n====Before updating:====")
    print_file_content(metafile)
    updater = TimestampUpdater(metafile)
    updater.updateLastModified()
    updater.updatepolicyid() 
    print("\n====After updating:====")
    print_file_content(metafile)
```

Comment: `ROW` doesn't have any attributes in your xml. you should check `if PolicyId.text == 'POL702965NGJ':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple solution, but one which uses lxml instead of xml.etree.ElementTree. For the sake of simplicity, I just focus exclusively on changing node values; obviously you'll have to adopt it for your other requirements.

```
policy = """[your xml above]""" #if parsing from an xml string
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.XML(policy.encode()) #if parsing from an xml string
doc = etree.parse(r'path\to\your\file\policy.xml') #if parsing from a file
replacements = ["some random policy number","some random date"]

targets = doc.xpath('//ROW[PolicyId="POL000002NGJ"]')
for target in targets:
    target.xpath('./PolicyId')[0].text = replacements[0]
    target.xpath('.//TransactionDate')[0].text = replacements[1]
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
# or to save to a new file:
doc.write('new_policy.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True,   encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

```
<TABLE>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>some random number</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>some random date</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>some random number</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>some random date</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>some random number</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X4</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>some random date</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL111111NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X4</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Thanks,I am parsing the XML path and update the policyid and need to generate the output file with updated values. below code has error,can u plz help~~from lxml import etree
import random, string
policy=etree.parse(r'C:\Users\relangovan\Desktop\Project_Document\XML\python.xml')
doc = etree.XML(policy.encode())
x = 'POL' + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=6)) + 'NGJ'
replacements = [x]
targets = doc.xpath('//ROW[PolicyId="POL000002NGJ"]')
for target in targets:
    target.xpath('./PolicyId')[0].text = replacements[0]
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
target.write('outp.xml')

Comment: Thanks Jack, You logic helps in <PolicyId> updates and track associated coverages to that policy. I am trying to parse the XML PATH instead of the document and Generates the Output file. I gets an error """AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'encode'"" and OUTPUT file not generating. Seems issue in                    
 ~~~policy = etree.parse(r'C:\Users\\XML\python.xml')
doc = etree.XML(policy.encode())  ------------ print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())

target.tree.write('output.xml')......Can you plz help here to understand,..

Comment: Thanks Much Jack, This helps me a lot in my requirement.

Comment: Jack, Sorry for coming back .For TransactionDate i have a logic before updating it for policy. I have an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"Same logic in xml.etree works fine. Can you plz see if you can help
doc = etree.parse(r'C:\'python.xml')
today = datetime.now()
TransactionDate = doc.find('TransactionDate')
previous_update = datetime.strptime(TransactionDate.text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
if previous_update < today:
                    TransactionDate.text = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
replacements = [Policy_Random_Choice , TransactionDate]

Comment: @Raj I'll take a look, but you should probably just post it as a separate question, per SO policy.

Comment: Jack, As you said raised a new request if you could help.. Thanks.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637023/i-have-an-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-text-wh

Comment: Jack, Can you please see if you could help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637023/i-have-an-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-text-wh?noredirect=1#comment112531104_63637023 i see this issue only when i use lxml. Same logic works well if i use xml.etree.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses python ElementTree XML lib. (not using an external lib).

It uses xpath and find the ROW having a specific PolicyId value.

It updates the date to the current date.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import datetime

xml = '''<TABLE>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>some random number</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>some random date</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>some random number</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>some random date</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>some random number</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X4</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>some random date</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL111111NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X4</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
</TABLE>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
rows_to_update = root.findall(".//ROW/[PolicyId='POL111111NGJ']")
for row in rows_to_update:
    row.find('TransactionDate').text = str(datetime.datetime.now())
ET.dump(root)
```