# I have an error ""AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"" while parsing datetime attribute in XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

For the node 'TransactionDate' i have a logic before updating it for policy"POL000002NGJ". The logic i have to implement with below code is If existing 'TransactionDate' < than today, then update to today datetime.now().
With the below logic,I have an error ""AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'""
Same logic if i use in "xml.etree.ElementTree" works fine but in lxml i am seeing issue. Can you plz see if you can help..

Transaction Date Format : 2020-03-23T10:56:15.00

Also is it possible to generate the output file only for the updated policy ""POL000002NGJ" with its associated nodes and values as below

```
--BEFORE UPDATING---

<TABLE>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL000002NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL000002NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00008A3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL111111NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X4</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-03-23T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
</TABLE>


--AFTER UPDATING (Only the updated policy with its other attributes)---

<TABLE>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL545678NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00002D3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-08-28T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <PolicyId>POL545678NGJ</PolicyId>
      <BusinessCoverageCode>COV00008A3X1</BusinessCoverageCode>
      <TransactionDate>2020-08-28T10:56:15.00</TransactionDate>
   </ROW>
</TABLE>
```

Code using is below

```
from lxml import etree
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random, string

doc = etree.parse(r'C:\Users\\XML\python.xml') #parsing from a file

#Random number generation for policy ID
Policy_Random_Choice = 'POL' + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=6)) + 'NGJ'

#Update Transaction date value if Current Transaction date < today for policy "POL000002NGJ"
today = datetime.now()
TransactionDate = doc.find('TransactionDate')
previous_update = datetime.strptime(TransactionDate.text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
if previous_update < today:
                    TransactionDate.text = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
                    
replacements = [Policy_Random_Choice , TransactionDate]
                    
targets = doc.xpath('//ROW[PolicyId="POL000002NGJ"]')
for target in targets:
    target.xpath('./PolicyId')[0].text = replacements[0]
    
    target.xpath('.//TransactionDate')[0].text = replacements[1]
    
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())

doc.write('new_policy.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True,   encoding="utf-8")
```

same logic works fine if i use xml.etree.ElementTree, not works with lxml.. i am doing something wrong, can anyone plz help

```
 def updateLastModified(self):
            today = datetime.now()
            for ROW in self.getMetadataRoot().findall('ROW'): ##
                TransactionDate = ROW.find('TransactionDate')
                previous_update = datetime.strptime(TransactionDate.text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
                if previous_update < today:
                    TransactionDate.text = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
                    self.getMetadataTree().write(self.meta_file)
```

Comment: why dont you go with my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605557/updating-xml-node-value-using-the-condition-in-python it works..

Comment: Thanks,Originally in my code i was using xml.etree.ElementTree. and had a issue in PolicyId.No issue with TransactionDate. For PolicyId i was generating the random.choices, Code given in original post updates new random values to every ROWS when PolicyId=POL702965NGJ.But my req. is new random PolicyId should assign same to every ROWS when "PolicyId=POL702965NGJ. So that i know the associated coverages for this policy.Actually I had issue here and full code is pasted in 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605557/updating-xml-node-value-using-the-condition-in-python